# Subadditivity of quantile function of Irwin-Hall distribution over n

Tags: probability, quantiles

I am struggling to prove that the quantile function of Irwin-Hall distribution is subadditve over n (the number of uniform distributed random variables that the Irwin-Hall distribution is created of).

$$
Q_{n+m}(p)\leq Q_{n}(p)+Q_{m}(p)
$$

in which $Q_n(p)=F_n^{-1}(z)$ and $F_n(z)$ is the CDF of the random variable $\textbf{Z}=\sum_{i=1}^n\textbf{X}_i$ and $\textbf{X}_i$s are all uniform iid random variables in $[0,1]$.

It could be easily proven through the simulation but I'm searching for a analytical proof.

I would really appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: It would be a pretty result if true, but it's not: consider any $p\lt 1/2$ and sufficiently large $m$ and $n$ for counterexamples.  Perhaps you meant to sum *iid* Uniform$[-1,1]$ variables?